# Application tried to push to a nil view controller on target <UINavigationController>

Tags: ios, pushviewcontroller

i have a navigation button called maps whereby i push to a view controller called mapviewcontroller and i keep on getting application tried to push to a nil view controller.

i tried changing the storyboard name, tried initializing my map object with nibname, and have an identifier set for the mapvc in storyboard and programmatically as well but nothing seems to work.

the code to the navigation button:

```
UIBarButtonItem *maps = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                           initWithTitle:@"Map"
                           style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered
                           target:self
                           action:@selector(mapIsPressed:)];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = maps;

}
-(void)mapIsPressed: (UIBarButtonItem*) paramsender
{
self.map=[[MapViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"map" bundle:nil];

self.map=[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"mapp"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:self.map animated:YES];

}
```

in my  mapvc i have a search bar button item that loads a table view when pressed and a map view. the code to the map vc:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.
[self.searchDisplayController setDelegate:self];
[self.mySearchBar setDelegate:self];

self.myMapView.delegate=self;

// Zoom the map to current location.
[self.myMapView setShowsUserLocation:YES];
[self.myMapView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
[self.myMapView setUserTrackingMode:MKUserTrackingModeFollow];



CLLocationManager *locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
locationManager.delegate=self;

[locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
[self.myMapView setRegion:MKCoordinateRegionMake(locationManager.location.coordinate,     MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.2, 0.2))];

MKLocalSearchRequest *request = [[MKLocalSearchRequest alloc] init];
request.region = self.myMapView.region;
request.naturalLanguageQuery = @"restaurant";

[UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = YES;
localSearch = [[MKLocalSearch alloc] initWithRequest:request];

[localSearch startWithCompletionHandler:^(MKLocalSearchResponse *response, NSError      *error){

    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;

    results = response;
    if (response.mapItems.count == 0)
        NSLog(@"No Matches");
    else
        for (MKMapItem *item in response.mapItems)
        {
            NSLog(@"name = %@", item.name);
            NSLog(@"Phone = %@", item.phoneNumber);

            [_matchingItems addObject:item];
            MKPointAnnotation *annotation =
            [[MKPointAnnotation alloc]init];
            annotation.coordinate = item.placemark.coordinate;
            annotation.title = item.name;
            [self.myMapView addAnnotation:annotation];
        }
}];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
} 
- (void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {

// Cancel any previous searches.
[localSearch cancel];

// Perform a new search.
MKLocalSearchRequest *request = [[MKLocalSearchRequest alloc] init];
request.naturalLanguageQuery = searchBar.text;
request.region = self.myMapView.region;

[UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = YES;
localSearch = [[MKLocalSearch alloc] initWithRequest:request];

[localSearch startWithCompletionHandler:^(MKLocalSearchResponse *response, NSError     *error){

    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;

    if (error != nil) {
        [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Map Error",nil)
                                    message:[error localizedDescription]
                                   delegate:nil
                          cancelButtonTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"OK",nil)     otherButtonTitles:nil] show];
        return;
    }

    if ([response.mapItems count] == 0) {
        [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"No Results",nil)
                                    message:nil
                                   delegate:nil
                          cancelButtonTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"OK",nil)     otherButtonTitles:nil] show];
        return;
    }

    results = response;

    [self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView reloadData];
}];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
return [results.mapItems count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:     (NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

static NSString *IDENTIFIER = @"SearchResultsCell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:IDENTIFIER];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle     reuseIdentifier:IDENTIFIER];
}

MKMapItem *item = results.mapItems[indexPath.row];

cell.textLabel.text = item.name;
cell.detailTextLabel.text = item.placemark.addressDictionary[@"Street"];

return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath     *)indexPath {
[self.searchDisplayController setActive:NO animated:YES];

MKMapItem *item = results.mapItems[indexPath.row];
[self.myMapView addAnnotation:item.placemark];
[self.myMapView selectAnnotation:item.placemark animated:YES];

[self.myMapView setCenterCoordinate:item.placemark.location.coordinate animated:YES];

[self.myMapView setUserTrackingMode:MKUserTrackingModeNone];

}
@end
```

Comment: Some quick thoughts: You initialize self.map with both @"map" from a nib, and @"mapp" from a UIStoryboard. I'm a little confused as to which you're actually using...

Comment: Also, check that self.map is a strong pointer, or else save the created MapViewController to an instance variable until it is added to the view hierarchy. Under ARC, a weak pointer with no other references will be automatically deallocated and set to nil, which may be causing the error.

Comment: Why are you using storyboards and not just using segues?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is most likely that self.map is immediately deallocated, assuming that the view is loading from the nib or storyboard correctly.

Ensure that self.map is declared as `@property (strong, nonatomic) MapViewController *map`, OR modify the code to save the newly created view controller to a locally scoped variable before setting self.map:

```
-(void)mapIsPressed: (UIBarButtonItem*) paramsender
{
    MapViewController *mapView = [[MapViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"map" bundle:nil]; // or load from storyboard

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:mapView animated:YES];

    self.map = mapView;
}
```

Under ARC, any object that has no references, or only weak references will be automatically deallocated. Any weak references to that object will be set to nil, which explains the error you're getting.

Now, once the view controller is pushed onto the view hierarchy, `UINavigationController` will maintain a strong reference to it, so you can use a weak reference after pushing it with no problems

Answer (score -1):

Your problem seems to be in your mapIsPressed method. You're overwriting the view controller you just created:

```
self.map=[[MapViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"map" bundle:nil];

self.map=[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"mapp"];
```

Comment: While this is bad/pointless code, it's not inherently wrong.  If that storyboard has a view controller with the identifier `mapp`, he definitely won't get this error, no matter how pointless it makes the first line of code.